# Is Int64 supported on all Windows versions?

Tags: windows, delphi, 64-bit, integer, 32-bit

If I use a variable of type `Int64`, will it work on all Windows versions: win95, 98, 2000, nt, xp, vista, win7? No matter what OS it is 32bit or 64bit? And no matter what CPU they are using?

I just want to be sure, that my program will work on all Windows versions.

Comment: Here's a similar related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959032/file-size-calculation-int64-and-differences-between-32bit-and-64bit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The size of datatypes provided by a language is not constrained by the operating system or hardware platform. I can have 64-bit integers on 32-bit platforms (or 16- or 8- or 11-bit, for that matter).

Comment: Some languages have data types whose size vary according to the target platform. Indeed Delphi does, NativeInt. I think I know what you mean, but it isn't phrased clearly.

Comment: Fair point.  But in general the precision of datatypes does not have anything to do with the OS.  A 64-bit OS is not required for 64-bit math.

Comment: Indeed arbitrary precision math can be done on very primitive machines. The point you are making, I think, is that the underlying platform does not constrain the size of operands which can be operated on.

Answer (score 5):

`Int64` variables are supported by the 32 bit Delphi compiler. All operations on `Int64` operands will give identical results no matter what platform (machine, OS etc.) the code executes on.

On 32 bit platforms the compiler has to use special routines to perform 64 bit arithmetic using the 32 bit machine instructions that are available. When targetting a 64 bit machine the compiler can use native 64 bit instructions. No matter, the end result is indistinguishable to you.

Note that if you execute a 32 bit Delphi executable on a 64 bit OS, you will still be using the 32 bit emulator, a.k.a. WOW64. From the perspective of the executable, you are running on a 32 bit machine. Unless you are using the new 64 bit compiler introduced in XE2, you will be producing 32 bit executables.

Answer (score 2):

The 64bit integers will work fine on a 32bit operating system.
Performance gains in using these data types however will only come when using code compiled  for a 64bit operating system - for this you would need Delphi XE2.

Meanwhile you have the benefits extra data capacity, but not extra execution speed (although this would not normally be a consideration for most applications).

Comment: To clarify, 64 bit integers are not faster than 32 bit integers, but native 64 bit integers are faster than non-native 64 bit integers.

Comment: That is correct, perhaps my description was not sufficiently clear.  To be more specific, operands which exceed the CPU register size will be slower than those which do not.  Therefore 64 bit integer operations will be faster on 64 bit CPUs running 64 bit operating systems (with 64 bit code), than if executing on a 32 bit system which will require more operations (= more CPU cycles) to achieve the same result.